# Openldap supportedControl Password Policy

Tags: .net, ldap, policy, openldap

Openldap supportedControl listed: 1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.27.8.5.1 (Password policy)

Using .Net DirectoryServices.Protocols, I've exhausted all possible methods of retrieving the response information provided by this control.

I'm using the latest Openldap Source built/running locally in a Cygwin environment with all PPolicy related config enabled in the build and the PPolicy configured and working/tested.

By modifying an example from the directory services programming guide, link:
http://dunnry.com/blog/2006/05/11/DotNetDevGuideToDirectoryServicesCompanionSiteLaunched.aspx

, to use a SearchRequest populated with a DirectoryControl configured to request the

Password Policy, gets me nothing.
Everything looks good in the Server Source:
http://www.openldap.org/devel/gitweb.cgi?p=openldap.git;a=blob_plain;f=servers/slapd/overlays/ppolicy.c;hb=HEAD

Has anyone had any luck using .Net DirectoryControls in a SearchRequest?

Here is some code I've been trying:

```
    _authConnect.AuthType = AuthType.Basic;
// credentials.UserName is a user DN format, w/password and null domain
_authConnect.Credential = credentials;
Debug.WriteLine("PV: " + _authConnect.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion);

var sr = //new ExtendedRequest();
         new SearchRequest(credentials.UserName, "(objectclass=*)", SearchScope.Base, null);
         //new DsmlAuthRequest(credentials.UserName);
        var isCritical = false;
    var ppolicy = "1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.27.8.5.1";
        // ppolicy request and response control is referred to by the same OID
        sr.Controls.Add(new DirectoryControl(ppolicy, null, isCritical, true));
    sr.Controls.Add(new DirectoryControl(ppolicy, new byte[8], isCritical, false));

try
{
  var response = (SearchResponse)_authConnect.SendRequest(sr);
  DirectoryControl[] c = response.Controls;
  if (c.Rank > 0 && c.GetLength(0) > 0)
  {
     Debug.WriteLine(c[0].Type + " value: " + c[0].GetValue());
  }
  SearchResultEntry entry = response.Entries[0];
  c = entry.Controls;
  if (c.Rank > 0 && c.GetLength(0) > 0)
  {
     Debug.WriteLine(c[0].Type + " value: " + c[0].GetValue());
  }  
  return true;
}
catch (LdapException ex)
{
  Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Have you determined that the authentication identity you use to set the authorization state (with bind) is allowed to use that request control?

Comment: nothing in the output from 'slapd -d -1' suggests there is a permission issue

Comment: I should have been more clear: do the directory server logs indicate that the request failed because the authorization state does not have permission to use that control? BTW, do not include the response control OID in the request. The response control, if present, shows up in the response from the server.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you and tried many things unsuccessfully and then ran out of time.  The problem as I noticed was that openldap was only sending the password expiration information in the bind request.  I found this out by enabling all logging on the server.  So I went about trying to find a way to use directory controls with a bind request.  There wasn't a way to do it using S.DS.P LdapConnection class that I could find.  I then went about hacking around with reflecting into the connection object and grabbing the ldaphandle variable.  With that I could use it to call into the c-api directly like S.DS.P does.  I looked around at the openldap sources and noticed that its tools use a sasl bind mechanism with no mechanism which in that library resorts back to a simple bind with the controls.  It doesn't work the same in winldap.  If you do that it will return a bad parameter response code.  The last thing I tried was calling the async version of ldap_bind and reading back the message.  Unfortunately no controls were ever in the response.  I think since I wasn't sending them they weren't getting returned even though the openldap log file said it was setting the warning.  That was my only hope for using any of the built-in winldap bind methods.

The last thing I was going to try but ran out of time would be to construct my own bind message with the controls and send them to the server using the ldap_extended_operation_s function.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366580(v=VS.85).aspx  If I get some extra time on this project I may go back and try that out.  If I do I'll report back here.  Ultimately though if this is the solution it may just be easier to use the ldapcsharp library from Novell.  It looks like it is possible to send a bind request with server controls using it.  I only explored the winldap api because I'm somewhat familiar with it and we're already pretty entrenched with using DirectoryServices.Protocols already.

Comment: I saw that Password expiration info in the bind requests too.  I believe that is sent back to auth requests made by a PAM module + slapd-search.  I briefly looked into using a PAM Module for Windows but it's not the best solution IMO.  Today, we are just requesting the policy and doing all the calculations ourselves.  So much for Openldap Controls!  I could never get any of them to work.  I think the problem lies in Openldap.  I'm going to look into a bugfix in the Openldap source once things quite down around here.